# How to Get Packet Bytes from a LiveCapture in Pyshark

Tags: python, python-3.x, packet, pyshark

Is there any way to get the packet bytes from a `LiveCapture` the same way you can get from loading a capture file?

Comment: you want the payloads?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I need